# Best option for DDoS protection on DigitalOcean server?

Tags: encryption, tls, web-application, network, ddos

I would not like to use CloudFlare since they effectively act as a man in the middle and handle unencrypted data.

Is there a CDN that mitigates the security risks that CloudFlare imposes?

If not, is there at least a DDoS protection service that is considered "secure"?

Comment: There is no way for an external DDoS protection service to work without having access to your data. If you don't trust CloudFlare, you have to find someone else you trust. There are some providers that provide DDoS protection, but you have to trust them too. You have to trust Digital Ocean right now. If you would state what exactly it is that keeps you from trusting CloudFlare, it would be easier to answer.

Comment: Hate to nitpick, but DigitalOcean too is man in the middle and handles unencrypted data.

Comment: @Josef this is the article that put me off CloudFlare: http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/07/14/cloudflare-we-have-a-problem/

Comment: @techraf so are you saying that even if my droplet on Digital Ocean is encrypted with a Let's Encrypt cert, DO can still view all traffic in plaintext? How do they do this??

Comment: @Josef to clarify I don't mind giving a DDoS protection service access to encrypted data, but are you saying it is impossible for a service to mitigate DDoS attacks unless they have access to my plaintext data?

Comment: @Jay By retrieving your private key from the disk and using it to decrypt the communication. The only thing that's stopping them is their business model and the agreement between them and you - the same applies to CloudFlare.

Comment: @techraf well to be fair that sounds like DO is more secure than CloudFlare from the perspective that CloudFlare already handles unencrypted data by default? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Jay How do you define "more secure"? Without insider knowledge it's **equally likely** that CloudFlare through the very fact of dealing with unencrypted data has much better procedures and employs more sophisticated security measures.

Comment: @techraf well the main thing that bothers me is that CloudFlare is used on 5% of clearnet sites, which leads me to believe that it would be the perfect network for the NSA/Privacy breachers to get themselves in with. So basically I am assuming that the CloudFlare network would be less secure based on it being a bigger target and also based on the fact that it is processing unencrypted information by default. Please let me know if I am misleading myself.

Comment: Please update your question to make clear it's about beliefs.

Comment: And don't forget that any reassuring advice it guidance you get on StackExchange might come from the NSA.

Comment: All the issues in the article, except that cloudflare can read your traffic, can be resolved by configuring cloudfare correct (require a valid TLS certificate at origin, reduce the captchas if you want,...) 
The trust issue you have can never be solved, DigitalOcean can access all your data, even the data you don't send via http because you have your software running at **their computers**!

Comment: @Josef No, you cannot. For example - when you get attacked, CloudFlare will switch you into "I'm Under Attack" mode forcibly, and you can't turn it off. Additionally, compromising the actual host systems is *much* harder to scale than a network MITM. This is already covered in the article, too.

Answer (score 4):

As @techraf and @josef commented, all DDoS providers have the same challenges:

- To effectively identify DDoS traffic, a mitigation provider needs to be connected inside your encryption termination point, or at least be a Man In the Middle.

Your concern regarding CloudFlare is the same concern you should have with them all. If you want DDoS mitigation, you need to let the mitigation provider have access. So start considering what the risks actually are from this. And what you need to do in terms of risk mitigation - perhaps contractual terms with the provider?

Comment: This is completely false; DDoS mitigation providers can block Layer 3/4 attacks *just fine* without ever seeing the (plaintext) content, and without needing to break encryption. Layer 7 attacks do not need to be handled by a mitigation provider, so that isn't a valid reason either.

Comment: Sven - no, only a small subset of DDoS can be handled without inspection. And do you know why? Because it looks exactly like real traffic, in many cases, so it needs to be analysed to distinguish it from real traffic.

Comment: Yes, and that small subset consists of the Layer 3/4 attacks, which I already pointed out. Which are also the only attacks that a mitigation provider *needs* to protect against. Mitigation appliances and companies have been doing this successfully for over a decade - hell, providers like OVH do it across their *entire network*.

Comment: Ahh - you misunderstood my meaning. that small subset is grand, but there is a vast amount of DDoS which needs to be analysed so it can be mitigated against.

Comment: Yes - by analyzing the *packet flow*, which doesn't require understanding what *contents* the packets contain. Layer 3/4 attacks are almost always volume-based attacks, which have nothing to do with the actual content of the packets (beyond tracking connections). These are the ones that mitigation providers need to defend against, and volume-based attack patterns are blatantly obvious.